# TOOLTIP: Option "sanitizeFn" provided type "window" but expected type "(null|function)"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-popover

I am running an ASP.NET Core 6 application which uses Jquery and Bootstrap - specifically their popovers.

I init the popovers with

`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`

and e.g. the html tag looks like this:

```
<div class="close-open-btn" data-expanded="true" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Open/Close" data-trigger="hover">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
</div>
```

Everything works fine, except when I use the Microsoft Edge Browser. Whenever I open the website, I instantly get the error message:

jquery.min.js:2

```
   Uncaught Error: TOOLTIP: Option "sanitizeFn" provided type "window" but expected type "(null|function)".
at Object.typeCheckConfig (util.js:142:17)
at t._getConfig (tooltip.js:689:10)
at i (tooltip.js:139:25)
at new i (popover.js:70:7)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (popover.js:157:16)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:3003)
at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1481)
at i._jQueryInterface [as popover] (popover.js:148:17)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (site.js:47:34)
```

The jquery and bootstrap sources/versions:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I've tried a few suggestions on different posts like turning off the sanitize option or changing the jquery versions, but nothing helped and it only occurs on Microsoft Edge (Using Version 104.0.1293.63.

Any ideas as to why this happens? Thanks in advance!